# My Windows Store application, involving C# and XAML, does not seem to load up

Tags: c#, xaml

So, I'm a newbie at XAML programming and I have just written a code involving only the basics. I put a background image over a blank page along with some buttons and textblocks but when I execute the program, it just gives me a blank, dark screen. Plus, it does not show any errors in the error list either. What am I doing wrong?

```
<Page
x:Class="App2.BlankPage1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App2"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="White">
<Image Source="Assets/test.jpg"/>
<Button  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="861,453,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="295" Height="69" BorderThickness="8,10" BorderBrush="#FF7682F7"/>
<Button  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="263,453,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="295" Height="69" BorderThickness="8,10" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="#FF7682F7" Click="Button_Click"/>
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1213,730,0,10" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="About us" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="28" Width="124" FontSize="24" Foreground="#FFA8A5A5" TextAlignment="Center" SelectionHighlightColor="#FF6A34E8"  >
        <TextBlock.DataContext>
            <local:BasicPage1/>
        </TextBlock.DataContext>
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Are you running it in debug mode (just press F5)? Do you get any exceptions? The error list is only there for compile time errors. That doesn't mean you don't have runtime errors

Comment: It is building and executing successfully without any failures or exceptions.

Comment: Here's the code that I have added.

<Grid Background="White">
    <Image Source="Assets/test.jpg"/>
    </Grid>

Comment: Show the complete code if you can. Do you insert the "test.jpg" image in your Assets folder? it must be inserted from visual studio.

Comment: Please add any detail to the question, not as comments.

Comment: is test.jpg in the Assets directory *and* included in the project?  Also, if not, you should see warnings in the output.  Please look there.

Comment: Yes, it is there in the Assets directory and the name of the file is exactly the same as I have written in the code. @PeterRitchie Actually, I do not have any more details since I have only started writing it.

Comment: @dachibox Updated the complete code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

As I can't see your full program code I can't be sure, but I bet your application is serving some other view than App.BlankPage1. This would explain no errors and a blank page. You should verify that you are in fact serving the right view upon load.

Comment: Hmm well I have not even added any other pages. This is the only page that I am currently having in the application.

Comment: Have you tried placing a break point in the constructor of the code behind file, and seen if it gets hit? Also, are you making a call to InitializeComponent (or what its name is..) in same constructor?

Comment: Break point? I haven't even written anything in C# yet. It's only XAML for now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<Page
   x:Class="App2.BlankPage1"
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   xmlns:local="using:App2"
   xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
   xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
   mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="White">
 <Image Source="Assets/test.jpg"/>
 <Button  Content="Button Test" Width="295" Height="69"/>
 <Button  Content="Button Test 2" Margin="263,453,0,0" Width="295" Height="69" Click="Button_Click"/>
 <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1213,730,0,10" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="About us" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="28" Width="124" FontSize="24" Foreground="#FFA8A5A5" TextAlignment="Center" SelectionHighlightColor="#FF6A34E8"/>
</Grid>
```

hope helps! greetings!

Comment: Did you tried create a new project and then complie it. When It works, and you have the test.jpg inside you project, it must work all well. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

OK, the problem is apparently solved but I don't know how. I sent the program to a friend and he corrected it for me WITHOUT changing even an alphabet in the code that I wrote. He said that I had to apply "send to back" to the background, but that does not make sense to me. Plus, I even tried to do it in another program i.e. sent the background image to back, but in my case, it didn't work with that either.